# Flash Technology in Embedded system

Tags: flash-memories

I have been always wondering how the process of burning code on a chip happens, I mean physically. I do that dozen of times, but the sense of how this is invented, how the hexcode interpreted in TTL Level.

I have been interested in Assembly language as makes me feel I am the chip, but how the transfer is done between hexcode and chip and how the flash technology is also working.

Please I need answer

Comment: Explain (in your question) what parts of your research you didn't understand. There will be plenty of articles on the Internet and no need for anyone to write one here for you. If you have a specific question then maybe we can help. Otherwise the question is too broad and will probably be closed.

Comment: Check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_memory and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_processing_unit#Operation.

Comment: This is not a site to ask for explanations that you could find by doing your own research on the topic. This is also not a discussion based forum. Please take the tour http://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour , learn how to interact with the community and read this  http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask  http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1):

At a basic level each bit of flash memory is a single FET transistor.

FETs are the basic building block of virtually all modern digital logic, a FET can be viewed as a switch. If there is a charge on one of the connections called the gate then the switch is on and current can flow between the other two pins. If there is no charge on the gate then the switch is off and current can't flow.

What is special about a flash chip is that the FETs have what is known as a floating gate. Instead of being electrically connected to a signal the gate isn't connected to anything, it's surrounded by an insulator. Once there is an electrical charge is on the gate it has nowhere to go, the transistor is permanently on. This is how a FLASH chip (or just about any form of EEPROM) keeps data when the power is turned off.

So how do you program the chip? No insulator is perfect. Above the floating gate is a control gate, if you put a sufficiently high (or low) voltage on that control gate you can force charge on (or off) of the floating gate allowing you to program or erase the memory.

Comment: Thanks so much andrew, I think you understand what I mean. I don't why mention this question is not suitable here, I think understanding  the scientific basics is mandatory as I think not all users of embeddd systems understand what is actually done at the machine level.

Comment: Andrew, please could you share a book explaining these technologies in detail, I need it.